# can I add 2 key at once to see TAG values

Tags: influxdb

I am getting result if I run individually both queries,

```
SHOW TAG VALUES from Test with key="Key1"
SHOW TAG VALUES from Test with key="Key2"
```

I want to combine both `Key` and wants to run a single query. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **OR** condition for this and it will give the data

```
SHOW TAG VALUES from Test with key=~/key1|key2/
```

Measurement Queries

```
select * from yourMeasurement where TagName =~/tag1|tag2/
```